# Faster way to link libraries in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt, opencv3.0

I'm using Eclipse CDT Neon Release 4.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. I work with project where I need to include and link OpenCV 3.1 libraries. For each individual project, I always go to Window > Preferences > C/C++ Build > Settings and add the paths and names of the relevant OpenCV libraries under "Cross G++ Compiler > Includes" and "Cross G++ Linker > Libraries".

Is there a way to avoid doing this for every new project, e.g. through a configuration file for the required libraries which I can simply copy for every project? Entering the same information each time, especially the names of the libraries, is very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Makefile projects rather than Managed Build projects (in the New C++ Project dialog, select "Makefile project" as the project type instead of "Executable"/"Shared Library"/etc.).

You would then have to write a makefile that specifies what compiler commands to run to build the project, including the flags for OpenCV's include path and library path.

Once you write the makefile once, you can reuse most of it for different projects, either by copy-and-paste, or by factoring out the reusable bits into a shared makefile that you include from the projects' makefiles.

I switched to using Makefile projects exactly for this reason.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. One thing to note is that the compilation and linking flags can be added to the Makefile by pkg-config, e.g. ` LDFLAGS = `pkg-config opencv --libs` `